# What is mean by "pacify stub networks" in ospf?

Tags: routing

I am told to always "passify my stub networks" I know a stub network is a network of end devices with only a single gateway (router) conntected to it.
But I don't now what is meant by "pacify" and theres not further context to it outside of that.
So what could that mean in relation to ospf?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it means blocking ospf traffic on an interface:

```
>passive-interface FastEthernet0/0
```